# How to upgrade python 3.7 to 3.10 in an anaconda without creating another environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I want to upgrade the python version in my Anaconda environment without creating another environment. Current environment is stuck on 3.7. I want to upgrade it to 3.10. Even the base(root) is on 3.9.7.
I have tried
`conda install -c anaconda python` 
and
`conda install python=3.10` .
After running the 2nd command It took around 1hr to examine all conflicts but it didn't upgrade.
I want to upgrade instead of creating a new environment is just because I have so many packages installed.

Comment: try `conda update --all` , if its not working , just download anaconda and install from scratch

Comment: you could try installing python with [mamba](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) instead